# How to create real time java file in codename one from xml

Tags: codenameone

I am working on a project which comprises different number of equipments for different users.

I want to create a page in codenameone which gives the status of those equipment to their users. How can I create it by parsing it from a XML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `XMLParser` class to generate a UI using the Codename One API. I'm assuming you mean runtime and not realtime which is a pretty different thing...